# Render table row and cell elements based on condition in ReactJS map loop

Tags: html, reactjs, dynamic

I want to generate 4 column structure from API data, so I implemented the below logic but it's not working.

Basically I want new table cells to display from every data entry of map function, but new table row generate after 4th data entry. Please help to generate and manage dynamic table elements.

```
 calcs.map(
                        calc =>  {
                            if(calc.order % 4 == 0)
                            {
                                if(calc.order != 1)
                                {
                                    </tr>
                                 }
                                <tr>
                            }
                             
                                <td key={calc.order}>
                                <button className='btn btn-warning' onClick={() => calcClicked(calc.sign)} 
                                            name={calc.order} key={calc.order}>{calc.sign}</button>
                                </td>
                            }
     )
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sandbox with an working example?

Comment: let me elaborate more,  lets say api giving me 16 records in json object , i want to display it on 4* 4 table dynamically while using json.map function? will you  help me with that

Comment: Elaborate in your post, not down here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by installing and using HTMLReactParser which allow me to execute code written in string variable.